# Main form fields only display data of first item selected within listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms that need to interact with each other. The parent form has 4 fields and an add button that saves data from each field to an instance of a class object. After its saved to an object the object is stored in a listbox, which the child form contains. I created a custom event to handle that stuff, but I am surely doing something wrong.

What's supposed to happen is that when both windows are open, and there is data in the listbox, whatever item that is selected from the child form listbox fills the parent form fields with the data from that object. When I test out my code, only the first item has the data properly filling the correct fields. If I click any other item after the first selection, the main form fields do not update at all.

Specific to my issue the child form has the following codes:

```
public EventHandler ListBoxItemClicked;
private void pPotionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PotionForm tempMain = new PotionForm(); //this was a test, nothing changed
    pPotionList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
    if (ListBoxItemClicked != null)
    {
        ListBoxItemClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    tempMain.Refresh();      // this too
}
```

The parent form has these codes

```
private void pListDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PotionList secForm = new PotionList();

    secForm.secFormBox.DataSource = potionBindList;

    PotionListChanged += secForm.HandlePotionListChanged;

    secForm.ChildPotionListChanged += HandleChildPotionListChanged;

    secForm.ListBoxItemClicked += HandleListBoxItemClicked; //this line

    secForm.Show();
}

public void HandleListBoxItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pTypeInput.SelectedItem = aPotion._type;
    pMagInput.Value = aPotion._magnitude;
    pNameInput.Text = aPotion._name;
    pBonusInput.Checked = aPotion._bonus;
}
```

I am currently using Visual Studio Community 2015 if that's relevant.

Comment: Need more information!: What is `PotionForm tempMain` ? What is the name of the parent `ListBox` ? What is `secForm.secFormBox` ? Of what type is `potionBindList` ?

Comment: Where is `aPotion` initialized?

Comment: `PotionForm tempMain` This is an instance of the parent form that I was attempting to use to refresh the main form so that when the selected item was selected, it could be refreshed with the new information. `secForm.secFormBox` This is an instance of the child form, and the child form's listbox. `potionBindList` This is a `BindingList<T>`

Comment: `aPotion` is initialized within `public partial class PotionForm : Form {  }`

Comment: up to now it looks as you would refresh a clean new instance of `PotionForm` in the child control and not the instance that you see as open window. Have you tried calling `this.Refresh()` in the `HandleListBoxItemClicked` method of the parent form? Also it is not clear from your posted code how the value of `aPotion` changes. " fills the parent form fields with the data from that object" that part is simply missing in your posted code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for not explaining it clearly, I have created 2 pastebins of the code for both the parent and child form (namespace excluded because of personal info.) _ Parent Form: [link](http://pastebin.com/CDP87tmi) _ Child Form: [link](http://pastebin.com/mLQypde6) _ I hope the code can clarify how the data in `aPotion` changes. if need be, I can post the class document for `Potion` itself? I have tried using `this.Refresh()` within `HandleListBoxItemClicked`, but that did not change the outcome when I tested it.

Comment: I had an idea of what the problem might be, now that helped a lot to verify it. I posted an answer, hope it can help you. Cool trick with the `public ListBox secFormBox` and the setter and getter bridge to access the private listbox! You could have also overloaded the constructor and passed the BindingList to the child to hook it up as `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after seeing all the necessary code I would say that the problem is that you never pass the values from the Child-Form to the Parent. Whenever the event `HandleListBoxItemClicked` is fired only the initial values of `aPotion` are written to the controls.

As a solution I would suggest to pass the `SelectedItem` as the sender when you fire the `ListBoxItemClicked` event in the childform:

**CHILD**

```
public EventHandler ListBoxItemClicked;
private void pPotionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Potion p = pPotionList.SelectedItem as Potion;

    pPotionList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
    if (p != null)
    {                
        if (ListBoxItemClicked != null)
        {
            ListBoxItemClicked(p, new EventArgs());
        }    
    }
}
```

Not you can use this information in the parent form and disperse the information as you please:

**PARENT**

```
public void HandleListBoxItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Potion p_parent = sender as Potion;

    if(p_parent != null)
    {      
        pTypeInput.SelectedItem = p_parent._type;
        pMagInput.Value = p_parent._magnitude;
        pNameInput.Text = p_parent._name;
        pBonusInput.Checked = p_parent._bonus;
    }
}
```

No refresh or anything else should now be necessary. Hope it helps

Comment: This did work, thank you! I had to replace the p with p_parent in the `HandleListBoxItemClicked` method. I assume that was a little typo?

Comment: @NerveSinge Yes that was a type. I thought in the last minute that it might be confusing if I call the variable in both methods `p` so I changed it, but apparently only in the declaration. Glad to hear that it helped